# NextJS: error - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error

> error - Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object.

My **\components\LayoutWrapper.js**

```
import Logo from "@next/svg"

<div className="mr-3 pt-2">
  <Logo src={icon} width="25px" height="25px" />
  {typeof siteMetadata.headerTitle === 'string' ? (
    <div className=""></div>
  ) : (
    siteMetadata.headerTitle
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: You're trying to display an Object in jsx instead of a Component

Comment: @dbuchet what to do now?

Comment: @dbuchet it was working earlier fine in my localhost, until I npm run build && npm run export

Comment: One of your page/components is returning an `object` rather than valid JSX elements. Please provide the relevant code that's triggering the error.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed and working

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import logo from '../assets/images/logo.svg'

<div className="mr-3 pt-2">
  <Image src={logo} width="25px" height="25px" />
  {typeof siteMetadata.headerTitle === 'string' ? (
    <div className=""></div>
  ) : (
    siteMetadata.headerTitle
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).